# How to handle server responses in dojo/store/JsonRest?

Tags: javascript, dojo

When using 'add' or 'put' on a dojo/store/JsonRest store, I would like to have an event handler for the server response, either on error or success.

I have tried adding an option like `error: function() {}` to the 'add' call, but this does not get triggered. Is there a special event or option that deals with the server response?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the answer is to use `then`, as it seems the `add` method returns a Deferred.

So you can do: `store.add(...).then(function(value){ /* success */ }, function(error){ /* error */ })`